# Is it possible to use the Python Embeddable package as the vscode interperter?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I have the vscode [python](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-python.python) extension, which requires a Python interpreter. When trying to use the Python installer, it asks for the admin password which I don't have. However, the embeddable comes with a Python executable, so I figured I could just use that. But when setting it to use the python.exe that comes in the embeddable package, it gives me this error.

[image]

I tried many things, like using pythonw.exe instead of python.exe. I tried extracting python311.zip, and it still gives the error.

Am I doing something wrong, or is it just impossible to use the embeddable package as the interperter?

Comment: Can you tell me how the problem is going?

Comment: @JialeDu Well I figured out that you can install python (not the embeddable) without admin. However, vscode still doesn't recognize it as a Python Interpreter. Another weird thing is that Pycharm (a different IDE) does recognize it. Maybe it could be because I'm using the portable version of vscode. I'll try to see if I can run the installer without admin.

Comment: @JialeDu Huh. Apparently vscode doesn't need to be installed with admin as well. I remember getting the admin prompt last time I tried, though. Anyway, trying to set the python (installed by installer, not embeddable) gives me the same message above.

Comment: On the vscode download page you can choose the user or system version. User version installation does not require an administrator password. But this has nothing to do with you using the python embeddable interpreter, can you tell me what the problem is now?

Comment: Where did you find that I can install non-embedded python without admin password? Only the embedded python package was unpacked in my answer.

Comment: @JialeDu I just downloaded this one https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.11.0/python-3.11.0-amd64.exe and it didn't give me an admin prompt.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/249411/discussion-between-jialedu-and-ok9090).

Comment: May I know what's going on with the problem? If you find the solution, you could click '✔' to mark it as an answer to change its status to Answered. It will also help others to solve a similar issue. See also [stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote](https://stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote)

Comment: @JialeDu No matter what I did vscode would not recognize my Python installation as a valid interpreter, so I just gave up.

Comment: If the problem no longer exists or is not needed, close it.

Answer (score 0):

##### Of course it is possible to use an embeddable package as an interpreter.

First download python 3.11 embeddable package from the [official website](https://www.python.org/downloads/windows/)( *Here is the windows system.* ),

[image]

and then **unzip** it to your computer. Older systems may require additional download and use of an unzip tool.

[image]

*Note that the path should preferably be in full English and without spaces and special characters.*

##### Next there are two ways to specify it as an interpreter in VS Code

**Method one**

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> --> `Python:Select Interpreter` --> `Enter Interpreter Path...`

  [image]
- Paste the **python.exe** path you just unzipped in the box and press Enter. On my computer this is:

  ```
  C:\Users\Admin\Downloads\python-3.11.0-embed-amd64\python.exe
  ```

  [image]
- Or you can click `Find...` and select the **python*.exe* you just unzipped in the opened folder window.

  [image]

**Method two**

- Add the following configuration in **settings.json**

  ```json
       "python.defaultInterpreterPath": "C:/Users/Admin/Downloads/python-3.11.0-embed-amd64/python.exe",
       // "python.defaultInterpreterPath": "C:\\Users\\Admin\\Downloads\\python-3.11.0-embed-amd64\\python.exe",
  ```

  *The path is the absolute path of **python.exe**. If you use a backslash `\`, remember to escape it. like my comment above*
- Then select **Use Python from `python.defaultInterpreterPath` setting** in the **Select Interpreter** panel.

  [image]

##### Run the code to output the interpreter path

[image]

Comment: I have tried both ways multiple times, yet it still gives me an error saying that an Invalid Python Interpreter has been selected. Maybe it's a problem with vscode?

Comment: Why not edit the question to tell us the detailed steps for each step you did. Just say you encountered an error, it is difficult for us to help you in detail. Please edit the question to describe in detail everything you did and the consequences that occurred, plus the necessary information is your OS, the python version you use, the vscode version, the python extension version in vscode, etc.

Comment: Follow my answer step by step. Please tell me at which step what is the problem? Could you please show it to me?